# Como inserto caracteres invisibles (oculto) en un texto

Tags: php, css, bootstrap, nodejs

hace un tiempo vi una web en ingles que se me hizo imposible traducirlo con cualquier traductor online , incluyendo google traductor.

Este es un pedazo de texto :

> Саrrоts аrе nоt јust fоr Вugs Вunnу! Іt іs а rісh sоurсе оf nесеssаrу
>   nutrіеnts аnd mіnеrаls. Іt іs а rісh sоurсе оf nесеssаrу nutrіеnts аnd
>   mіnеrаls. Іt іs оnе оf thоsе mіrасlе соnсосtіоns thаt іs gооd fоr
>   vаrіоus рurроsеs. Саrrоts hаvе а wеаlth оf vаluаblе nutrіtіоn аnd whеn
>   уоu јuісе thеm, уоu саn gеt а соnсеntrаtеd dоsе оf thеіr hеаlіng
>   роwеr. Frоm bаlаnсіng blооd sugаr, іmрrоvіng blооd hеаlth, rеlіеvіng
>   соngеstіоn, fіghtіng іnflаmmаtіоn аnd сlеаnsіng thе kіdnеуs tо
>   рrоtесtіng еуеsіght, brаіn funсtіоn аnd fіghtіng Lеukеmіа, саrrоt
>   јuісе bеnеfіts саn hеlр nеаrlу еvеrу раrt оf уоur bоdу! Drіnkіng
>   саrrоt јuісе dаіlу іs а hаbіt thаt еvеrуоnе shоuld stаrt, аs іt іs
>   bоth hеаlthу аnd tаstу аs wеll.

Por lo que vi tiene caracteres ocultos dentro del texto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El texto lo puede copiar y pegar donde sea ( editor de texto , word ect...) no se altera y no se puede traducir

¿Tienen alguna idea de como hacer eso con php?

Saludos

Answer (score 2):

No son caracteres invisibles, es el alfabeto cirílico: UTF-8 'd0a1' = C, 'd092' = B, etcétera.. pero no sé como lo han hecho para asociar el carácter cirílico al carácter latin así...ingenioso? algún problema raro de codificación?

- http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr36/#Mixed_Script_Spoofing
- https://github.com/phpbb/area51-phpbb3/blob/master/phpBB/develop/generate_utf_confusables.php

Answer (score 1):

De forma rápida y sencilla, podrías intercalar elementos `<span></span>` con caracteres alfanuméricos aleatorios entre el texto.

De esta forma, podrías tener:

```
<style>
    .hide-text { display: none; }
</style>
```

E insertar este elemento `<span class="hide-text">{textoaleatorio}</span>` entre los caracteres de tu texto. No solo puedes insertar caracteres, sino textos completos. Siempre y cuando la salida de ese texto sea html.

Answer (score 0):

Quizá era un tipo de fuente con algún carácter que era invisible "o al menos", muy delgado.

Tendrías que crear tu propia fuente y crear un carácter invisible o muy delgado y ponerlo entre tus letras/palabras.